# .bashrc not sourced from script when run as a cron job

Tags: bash, cron

I have a bash script that is invoked from a cron job which has the following lines:

```
source ~/.bashrc
jruby run.rb
```

`.bashrc` adds `jruby` to the path.

I am able to invoke the script directly on a terminal but the cron fails with "jruby not found"

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your must set your `PATH` in the script so that  `jruby` is included in it.

Comment: thanx for the reply. jruby is set in the path in .bashrc . Isnt source "~/.bashrc" enough ?

Comment: setting jruby and exporting path from the script worked, but I am still curious why sourcing to the env in the script doesnt work from crontab !

Comment: On many systems, cron jobs are exexuted by `sh`, not by your login shell. The `source` command is a bashism; use `.` instead, and use `$HOME` rather than `~` to refer to your home directory (and/or move the `PATH` declaration to a Bourne-compatible location, such as `.profile`).